# Istio break SFTP communication

Tags: kubernetes, sftp, istio

I have a simple stateful with SFTP features and a second service try to connect to it.

When ISTIO is enabled, the connection is closed by the sftp service.
We can find this log:

```
Bad protocol version identification '\026\003\001'
```

The routing is OK.

The service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 22
      targetPort: 22
      protocol: TCP
      name: tcp-sftp
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: foo-bar
```

I try to add a VirtualService with no luck:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: foo-bar-destination-virtualservice
  namespace: bar
spec:
  hosts:
    - foo.bar.svc.cluster.local
  tcp:
    - match:
        - port: 22
      route:
        - destination:
            host: foo.bar.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 22
```

The workaround is to disabled the sidecar on the sftp pod for now:

```
sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems Envoy proxy (and Istio by proxy) does not support SFTP protocol ([referecce](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7664#issuecomment-411948731)).
Your workaround is currently the only way to make it work.

If you want your auto-discovered services in the mesh to route/access your SFTP service, you can additionally create [`ServiceEntry`](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) pointing to it.

Comment: I was thinking istio support tcp, if the protcol is not supported ?